# CodeIgniter pagination not working with multi language website

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

It is first time that developed website with codeigniter and i think it is a very usefull framework. I able to create a multilanguage website with the language in the url.

I folow up this website "http://jeromejaglale.com/doc/php/codeigniter_i18n".

Everything works correctly. The problem is that I can't operate pagination. when I click on link 2 to go to the second page of the pagination i got redirect to homepage.

This is my link http://test.lan/en/blog

This is my pagination link http://test.lan/blog/2

Thanks for any help please.

Here my code:

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'blog';
            $config['total_rows'] =  $this->blog_model->countPost('post');
        $config['per_page'] = 5;
            $config['uri_segment'] = 2;
            $choice = $config['total_rows']/$config['per_page'];
            $config['num_links'] = round($choice); 

            $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div id="data-table_paginate" class="dataTables_paginate paging_full_numbers">';
            $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';
            //Customizing the "Digit" Link
            $config['num_tag_open'] = '';
            $config['num_tag_close'] = '';
            //Customizing the "Current Page" Link
            $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<a class="paginate_active" tabindex="0">';
            $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a>';
            $config['anchor_class'] = 'class="paginate_button"';

            //Customizing the "Next" Link
            $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
            $config['next_tag_open'] = '';
            $config['next_tag_close'] = '';

            //Customizing the "Previous" Link
            $config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';
            $config['prev_tag_open'] = '';
            $config['prev_tag_close'] = '';

            $this->pagination->initialize($config);

            $page = ($this->uri->segment(2))? $this->uri->segment(2) : 0;
    $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

Comment: Did you used Codeigniter pagination library?If so can I see your initialization config for pagination?

Answer (score 0):

It lucky now I find code fixed issue, 
I only change

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'blog';
```

to

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url() . $this->lang->lang() . '/blog';
```